# Historical isobaric charts?

Tags: meteorology, barometric-pressure, database

I am looking for a small-scale isobaric chart, which encompasses central Africa. I am interested in the time span of the past few months.

Do you know where to find it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have found an archive of small-scale charts encompassing part of Africa [here](https://www.wetterzentrale.de/reanalysis.php?jaar=2019&maand=1&dag=11&uur=000&var=45&map=1&model=nws).